# How to disable submit buttons until the character limits of name field are not fixed

Tags: php

I want to disable the submit button until the user fixes character limits of FIRST NAME, MIDDLE NAME and LAST NAME etc.

Below is the code in which i have set the alert for character limit but not able to disable submit buttons:

```
function myuk () {  remove_action( "gform_field_input" ,
        "wps_jrp_field_input", 10, 5 ); } add_action( 'after_setup_theme',
        'myuk' ); // Adds the input area to the external side add_action(
        "gform_field_input" , "wps_jrp_field_input2", 10, 5 ); function
        wps_jrp_field_input2 ( $input, $field, $value, $lead_id, $form_id ){
            if ( $field["type"] == "jrp" ) {                $input_name = $form_id .'_' . $field["id"];
                $tabindex = GFCommon::get_tabindex();       $css = isset( $field['cssClass'] ) ? $field['cssClass'] : '';       $tmp = '<div
        class="ginput_complex ginput_container"
        id="input_'.$input_name.'">'; 

        //First name
        $fieldName = 'input_'.$field["id"].'_1';
        if($_POST[$fieldName]){
            $nameValue1 = $_POST[$fieldName];
        }
        $tmp .= '<div style="padding:0;" class="col-sm-4_5">
                <span id="input_'.$input_name.'_1_container" class="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="'.__("First name (as on passport)","Avada").'" value="'.$nameValue1.'"
name="input_'.($field["id"]+0.1).'" id="input_'.$input_name.'_1"
class="textbox-placeholder-'.$input_name.'_1 gform_jrp
'.$field["type"] . ' ' . esc_attr($css) . '">
                </span>
                </div>';

        //Middle name
        $fieldName = 'input_'.$field["id"].'_3';
        if($_POST[$fieldName]){
            $nameValue3 = $_POST[$fieldName];
        }
        $tmp .= '<div style="padding:0;" class="col-sm-4_5">
                <span id="input_'.$input_name.'_3_container" class="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="'.__("Middle name (as on passport)","Avada").'" value="'.$nameValue3.'"
name="input_'.($field["id"]+0.3).'" id="input_'.$input_name.'_3"
class="textbox-placeholder-'.$input_name.'_3 gform_jrp
'.$field["type"] . ' ' . esc_attr($css) . '">
                </span>
                </div>';


        //Last name
        $fieldName = 'input_'.$field["id"].'_2';
        if($_POST[$fieldName]){
            $nameValue2 = $_POST[$fieldName];
        }
        $tmp .= '<div style="padding:0;" class="col-sm-4_5">
                <span id="input_'.$input_name.'_2_container" class="">
                <input type="text" placeholder="'.__("Last Name (as on passport)","Avada").'" value="'.$nameValue2.'"
name="input_'.($field["id"]+0.2).'" id="input_'.$input_name.'_2"
class="textbox-placeholder-'.$input_name.'_2 gform_jrp
'.$field["type"] . ' ' . esc_attr($css) . '">
                </span>
                </div>';


        $input_title = 'input_'.$field["id"].'_01';
        $input_fname = 'input_'.$field["id"].'_1';      $input_mname = 'input_'.$field["id"].'_3';
        $input_lname = 'input_'.$field["id"].'_2';
        if($_POST[$input_title] || $_POST[$input_fname] || $_POST[$input_mname] || $_POST[$input_lname]){
            if(empty($_POST[$input_fname])){$_POST[$input_fname]='(NULL)';}
            if(empty($_POST[$input_mname])){$_POST[$input_mname]='(NULL)';}
            if(empty($_POST[$input_lname])){$_POST[$input_lname]='(NULL)';}
            $input_hidden = $_POST[$input_title] .' '. $_POST[$input_fname] .' '. $_POST[$input_mname] .' '.
$_POST[$input_lname];
        }

        $tmp .= '<input type="hidden" name="input_'.$field["id"].'" id="hidden_input_'.$input_name.'" value="'.$input_hidden.'">';
        $tmp .= '<div class="gf_clear gf_clear_complex""></div></div><div
style="clear:both;"></div>';


        $tmp .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery("#input_'. $input_name .'_01, #input_'. $input_name .'_1, #input_'.$input_name .'_2, #input_'.$input_name
.'_3").change(function(){
                    str = jQuery("#input_'.$input_name .'_01").val() +"/"+ jQuery("#input_'.$input_name .'_1").val() +"/"+
jQuery("#input_'.$input_name .'_2").val() +"/"+
jQuery("#input_'.$input_name .'_3").val();;
                    str1= jQuery("#input_'.$input_name .'_1").val();
                    str2= jQuery("#input_'.$input_name .'_2").val();
                    str3= jQuery("#input_'.$input_name .'_3").val();
                    if(str1.length >= 30){
                    alert("The maximum character for first name is 30.");
                    }

                    if(str2.length >= 30){

                    alert("The maximum character for last name is 30.");
                    }

                    if(str3.length >= 60){

                    alert("The maximum character for middle name is 60.");
                    }
                    jQuery("#hidden_input_'.$input_name.'").val(str);
                });
                </script>';

        return sprintf($tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every line of your code needs to have 4 spaces before it, or it will end up looking super ugly like it does currently.

To answer your question, Something like this using jQuery should do fine.

```
//when the user clicks submit, do a check on all inputs
$('#theForm').submit(function(e) {
    //prevent form from sending anyway
    e.preventDefault();
    //define min length of inputs
    var minLength1 = 30;
    var minLength2 = 60;
    ...
    //get lengths of all inputs currently
    var inputLength1 = $('#input1').val().length;
    var inputLength2 = $('#input2').val().length;
    ...
    //check and see if they are all above the threshold
    if (inputLength1 >= minLength1 && inputLength2 >= minLength2 && ...) {
        return true;
    } else {
        //if they're not all above the threshold, return false (tell form it cant send)
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Y can't it be limited in the front-end itself.

```
<input type="text" ... minlength=10>
```